# What equation would match this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to find an equation that would give me a continuous set of solutions for this series.

$$x=1; y=1$$
$$x=2; y=1+\frac{1}{2}$$
$$x=3; y=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}$$
$$x=4; y=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}$$

where the nth term is $\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^{(x-1)}$

My original motivation for this question was based on the use of relief pitchers in baseball.  There is a general observation that historically, in certain time periods, the second relief pitcher out of the bullpen pitches approximately 60% as many innings as the first, and the third pitches approximately 60% as many innings as the second, and so on.  This allows a team to estimate the relative value of the nth relief pitcher in a bullpen.  It is also an accurate predictor of relief pitcher usage in strat-o-matic baseball simulation with certain setting.

Comment: seems to be a geometric one? Use knowledge of geometric sequences and series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence you describe is $a_n = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \ldots + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$, or written more succintcly, $a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2^k}$.

Note that it is a sequence and not a series (it is, however, the sequence of partial sums of the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}$).

You ask for the 'set of solutions' of this sequence, which does not make sense because an equation has a solution, a sequence does not. I can only guess that you mean to find a simpler formula for $a_n$. Since $a_n$ is a partial sum of a geometric series with quotient $\frac{1}{2}$ we have by the well known formula $a_n = \frac{1-(\frac{1}{2})^n}{1-\frac{1}{2}} = 2 - (\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and this approaches $2$ as $n\to\infty$.

The general formula is that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty q^n = \frac{1}{1-q}$ for every $-1<q<1$. So for $q=\frac{1}{2}$ we have that the limit is $2$, for $q=0.6$ the limit is $\frac{1}{1-0.6}=2.5$, and so on.

A proof of this formula can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum

Comment: Yes that is basically what I was looking for, but I was hoping I would be able to generalize the equation to other sequences.  If we change it to 1 + .5 + .5^2 + .5^3.....  I knew this would approach 2.  I wanted to be able to do the same, replacing .5 with other values such as .6 as in 1 + .6 + .6^2 + .6^3.....I know that approaches something like about 2.4.  Is there a way to find that limit for any probability in that spot?

Comment: @JosephHirsch I edited the answer with the general formula.

Comment: I am curious, I edited to question to give an explanation of utility.  How can I reopen it?  I got what I wanted anyway, so it doesn't matter.